# Strange behavior on table and table-cell with percentage width

Tags: css, css-tables

I recently stumbled upon a question here where someone was trying to get a proper line-behind behavior on their headers. Something like this:

[image]

Their implementation yielded different results across different headers, and hence the question. The implementation was quite odd by using `table` for the element and `table-cell` for the `:before` and `:after`. The resulting behavior was for me quite surprising. I made a test on [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1ha63gm5/1/), have a look.

You'll see that I have two classes; `a` and `b`, where the former has a width of 25% and the latter 40%. Despite this, the `b` is nearly 5 times wider than `a`. Setting them to 40% and 45% respectively makes `b` twice as large as `a`. This is totally unexpected behavior for just a 5% difference. The length of the text seems to affect this too.

I get that this implementation is bad and that it would "break". However, I'd like to know *why* it breaks the way it does. This makes no sense to me.

```css
div {
  display: table;
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
}
div.b:before,
div.b:after {
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">text</div>
<div class="a">some more text</div>

<div class="b">text</div>
<div class="b">some more text</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto tabular layout is not specified by the standard, so I recommend against using this kind of percentage tricks, which will probably break on some browsers.

However, it seems most browsers behave like this:

- The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements will take the specified percentage of the table.
- The text is wrapped inside an anonymous cell which has the width of the text. That will represent the remaining percentage left by the pseudo-elements.
- The width of the table will be determined by the constraints above.

So if you have `width: 25%`, the text will take the remaining `50%`.

```
tablewidth = textwidth / 50% = 2 * textwidth
pseudowidth = 25% * tablewidth = 0.5 * textwidth
```

If you have `width: 40%`, the text will take the remaining `20%`.

```
tablewidth = textwidth / 20% = 5 * textwidth
pseudowidth = 40% * tablewidth = 2 * textwidth
```

If you have `width: 45%`,  the text will take the remaining `10%`. That is, the table will double its width with respect to the previous case, if the text is the same.

```
tablewidth = textwidth / 10% = 10 * textwidth
pseudowidth = 45% * tablewidth = 4.5 * textwidth
```

Of course, things start to get tricky if the desired table width calculated as described above exceeds the containing block. Then

- The table will be as wide as the containing block
- The text cell will have the width resulting of resolving the remaining percentage left by the pseudo-elements. That will be less than the preferred width of the text, so the text will wrap into multiple lines.

  However, the text cell won't be narrower than the minimum required width of the text. That will usually be the width of the longest word, but may change due to e.g. `word-break: break-all` or `white-space: nowrap`.
- The remaining space left by the text will be equally distributed among the pseudo-elements.

  If the remaining space is negative, the pseudo-elements will have 0 width, and the table will grow (overflowing the containing block) in order to compensate that.

Comment: That's quite interesting. So the change from `40%` to `45%` essentially means that the `textwidth` went from being `20%` the tables width to `10%`. That explains the doubling of the tables' width. Do you have any resources I can study? Thanks.

Comment: @Chris You can see a non-normative algorithm for auto table layout suggested in [CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout). Recently there has been some work in [CSS Tables 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-tables-3/), but it's still a draft and I'm not sure it reflects what implementations do.